# Unable to exchange cookie between Spring and Angular2

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, angular, cookies

I got following oauth2 implementation:

1. My front-end (SPA), written in angular2 is served from `frontend.mydomain.com` .
2. When user is logging in, he is connecting to `auth.mydomain.com`, backend responds with access token, and set httpOnly cookie containing refresh token.

this is how I set cookie:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/retrieve", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getToken(HttpServletResponse resp, @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    String[] tokens = //retrieve tokens logic, values are not important

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", tokens[1]);
    resp.addCookie(cookie);

    return tokens[2];
}
```

3. Data is retrieved from `resources.mydomain.com` (requests are send with access token)
4. when token expires I want to refresh it via sending request to `auth.mydomain.com` - server should retrieve refresh token from cookie and respond with new access token.

I think that I have issue in point 2, which is affecting point 4 - no cookie is sent. 
`org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException: Missing cookie 'token' for method parameter of type Object`

Why? What can I do to force browser to save and send this cookie?

When I take a look inside my browser (developer tooles) I can see that rest response sends cookie: 
[image]

But no cookie is stored in the browser:
[image]

Comment: Since the cookie is apparently already sent correctly, this is probably not a Spring question at all. I'm guessing it's an issue with your Angular code (in step 4) – do you set the ["withCredentials" RequestOption](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html#withCredentials-anchor) when doing the refresh request?

Comment: nope, I am not. Should I?

Comment: I changed my code accordingly: this.http.post(AUTHENTICATION_ENDPOINT + "/refresh", new RequestOptions({withCredentials: true}))   still same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in front-end side. I was not using 'withCredentials' option. It should be used as well for request which is setting up cookie, and for request which is sending cookie:

retrieving cookie:

```
this.http.get(
    AUTHENTICATION_ENDPOINT + "/retrieve?username=" + login + "&password=" + password + "&remember=" + remember, 
    new RequestOptions({withCredentials: true})
)
```

sending cookie:

```
this.http.get(
     AUTHENTICATION_ENDPOINT + "/refresh", 
     new RequestOptions({withCredentials: true})
)
```