# Spring Security CSRF Cookie ignored by chrome

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

I am trying to implement CSRF protection using spring and angular. In Spring, I configured:

```
CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository = new CookieCsrfTokenRepository();
    cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookieHttpOnly(false);
    cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
    cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookieName("test");
    cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setHeaderName("test");
```

Which works as can be seen in the server's response:

[Response headers showing Set-Cookie: test=....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghi2C.png)

But somehow the cookie is not being set. When looking at my the cookies for the website or even all cookies of Chrome which I freshly cleaned before, there simply are no cookies at all:

[No cookies shown by chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RqzN.png)

The setting in Chrome is "Allow all cookies".

I read that the set-cookie header sometimes causes troubles on localhost and without https, so I also tried on my deployment server with the same result unfortunately. Any ideas on why that happens?

Comment: Could this be the same issue you're seeing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568828/unable-to-exchange-cookie-between-spring-and-angular2

Comment: That really fixed it! Thank you so much!